# Model not found error in 3d-pose-baseline

Tags: python, tensorflow, 3d

I was trying to use [3d-pose-baseline](https://github.com/ArashHosseini/3d-pose-baseline) to convert the 2d keypoints to 3d but when i run the pretrained model using the following command

```
python src/predict_3dpose.py --camera_frame --residual --batch_norm --dropout 0.5 --max_norm --evaluateActionWise --use_sh --epochs 200 --sample --load 4874200
```

I am getting the following error:

```
NotFoundError (see above for traceback): Restoring from checkpoint failed. This is most likely due to a Variable name or other graph key that is missing from the checkpoint. Please ensure that you have not altered the graph expected based on the
checkpoint. Original error:

NewRandomAccessFile failed to Create/Open: experiments\All\dropout_0.5\epochs_200\lr_0.001\residual\depth_2\linear_size1024\batch_size_64\no_procrustes\maxnorm\batch_normalization\use_stacked_hourglass\predict_17\checkpoint-4874200.data-00000-of-00001 : The system cannot find the path specified.
; No such process
         [[node save/RestoreV2 (defined at D:\Programming\PoseNet\tf-pose-estimation\3d-pose-baseline\src\linear_model.py:151) ]]
```

I have downloaded the pretrained model and the path the error claims to not exist does exist in my system.

Where could the problem be and how to resolve it? I even tried retraining the model as in the mentioned repository but it fails to write the checkpoint after every 100 batches and finally after 1 epoch it shows the same error as above.